# Optaplanner - multithreading

Tags: optaplanner

I am using optaplanner 8.17.FINAL with Java 17.0.2 inside a kubernetes cluster, my server has 32 cores + hyper threading. My app scales to 14 pods and I use moveThreadCount = 4 . On a single run, everything works fine, but on a parallel run, the speed of the optaplanner drops. With 7 launches, the drop is insignificant, 5-10%. But with 14 launches, the speed drop is about 50%. Of course, you can say that there are not enough physical cores, but I'm not sure that hyperthreading works like that. In resource monitoring, I see that 60 logical cores are involved with 14 launches, but why then do the speed drop twice?

I'm tried to inscrease heap size and change garbage collector (G1GC, SerialGC, ParallelGC), but it has little effect

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on hyperthreading by any means but perhaps OptaPlanner, by
fully utilizing the entire core(s), cannot benefit from HT so much. If so, you just don't have enough CPU cores to run so many solvers in parallel, which leads to context switching and performance drop, as a result.

You can prove that by adding more cores. If it helps, it means there is no artificial bottleneck for this amount of tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also tend to this conclusion, but I wanted to confirm it with experts in the optaplanner.

Comment: I also wanted to clarify how the -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=n parameter can affect. My application logs show: The resolvedMoveThreadCount (4) is higher than the availableProcessorCount (1), which is counter-efficient. Most likely this is due to the docker and kubernet environment. I usually add the jvm option to override this setting, but I don't see a significant performance difference. Does this setting matter? If so, is there an optimal formula? There is very little in the documentation about this.

Comment: The `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=n` should work, but if you want more control over the move threads, simply override the  `<moveThreadCount/>` setting in the solver configuration XML.
See https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#multithreadedIncrementalSolving.